# Calculate ${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&1\\ { - 1}&3 \end{array}} \right]^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Evaluate ${\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> 1&1\\
> { - 1}&3
> \end{array}} \right]^n}$ knowing that $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> 1&1\\
> { - 1}&3
> \end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> 1&0\\
> 1&1
> \end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> 2&1\\
> 0&2
> \end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
> 1&0\\
> { - 1}&1
> \end{array}} \right]$

I am quite new to linear algebra, so my first thought is to calculate each of the matrices and multiply them, but it is really long and tricky.

Is there any better way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Use the associative property of matrix multiplication and consider $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0\\
{ - 1}&1
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0\\
1&1
\end{array}} \right]$ and $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&1\\
0&2
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
2&1\\
0&2
\end{array}} \right]$ etc

Comment: To typeset a matrix, instead of `{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}a&b\\c&d\end{array}} \right]^n}` you can just use `\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}`. See the [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
{ - 1}&1
\end{bmatrix}$ are inverse of each other.

Comment: Does that means $\left[ {\matrix{
   1 & 1  \cr 
   { - 1} & 3  \cr 

 } } \right] = \left[ {\matrix{
   2 & 1  \cr 
   0 & 2  \cr 

 } } \right]$?

Comment: Of course not. How could they be equal? $1\ne 2$, $-1 \ne 0$ and $3 \ne 2$. It means you can write the first matrix as $ABA^{-1}$

Comment: Now I get it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right) \to A^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
so $$B=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 3
\end{matrix}\right)=A^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)A$$ now you able to find the power of $n$